# Make two identical records appear using union but not the unnecessary records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am taking a `UNION` which is OK until today I faced one problem in the 2nd query where there are chances of appearing two or more identical records and should be shown but union being union is only taking one out of those. If I put `UNION ALL` then some unnecessary duplicates appear which I don't want. What to do?

```
select Com.CompanyCode, B.BranchCode,P.ProjectCode as 'ProjectCode',G.GLAccountNo,COA.ShortText, G.DocCurrency, G.DocCurrencyAmount, 
G.Currency as 'localCurrecny', G.Amount as 'LocalAmount', S.InvoiceNo as 'Reference', 
cast(S.BillingDocumentNumber as varchar(100)) as 'DocumentNumber', '' as 'Document Type',
cast(S.BillingDate as date) as 'PostingDate', cast(S.PODate as date) as 'DocmentDate', 
G.DC,'' as 'Clearing Document', S.AccountingAssignment as 'Assignment', 
'' as 'Department', '' as 'ServiceLineCode','' as 'ProjectCode', '' as 'OffSettingAcctNo', S.TextDescription as 'Text'
from GLedger G
left join Company Com on G.CompanyID = Com.CompanyID
left join Branch B on G.BusinessArea = B.BranchCode
--inner join LedgerTypes L on G.LedgerType_ID = L.ID
inner join Sales S on G.MainID = S.SalesID and G.LedgerType_ID = '3'
left join Projects P on S.AccAssignmentWBSElementID = p.Project_ID
Left join COA on G.GLAccountNo=COA.GLAccount

where
(G.CompanyID = @CompanyID)AND
((G.GLAccountNo >= @TempGLAccountNoFrom) AND (G.GLAccountNo <= @TempGLAccountNo))AND
((G.DocumentNumber >= @TempDocumentNumberFrom) AND (G.DocumentNumber <= @TempDocumentNumberTo))
AND (cast(S.BillingDate as date) between cast(@TempFromDate as date)
AND cast(@TempToDate as date))
AND ISNULL(g.Active,0)= 1
AND ((G.BusinessArea = @BusinessArea or @BusinessArea is null))

union

select Com.CompanyCode, B.BranchCode,P.ProjectCode as 'ProjectCode',G.GLAccountNo,COA.ShortText, G.DocCurrency, G.DocCurrencyAmount, 
G.Currency as 'localCurrecny', G.Amount as 'LocalAmount', '' as 'Reference', cast(G.DocumentNumber as varchar(100)) as 'DocumentNumber', 
'' as 'Document Type',sal.BillingDate as 'PostingDate', CAST(st.PricingDate as date) as 'DocmentDate', G.DC,'' as 'Clearing Document', '' as 'Assignment', 
D.DepartmentCode as 'Department', S.Name as 'ServiceLineCode', P.ProjectCode as 'ProjectCode', '' as 'OffSettingAcctNo', '' as 'Text'
from GLedger G
left join Company Com on G.CompanyID = Com.CompanyID
left join Branch B on G.BusinessArea = B.BranchCode
--inner join LedgerTypes L on G.LedgerType_ID = L.ID
inner join SalesTransactions ST on G.SubID = ST.SalesTransactionID and G.LedgerType_ID = '4'
left join Department D on G.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID
left join ServiceLineMaster S on G.ServiceLineID = S.ID
left join Projects P on ST.ProjectID = p.Project_ID
Left join COA on G.GLAccountNo=COA.GLAccount
inner join Sales sal
on sal.SalesID= st.SalesID

where
(G.CompanyID = @CompanyID)AND
((G.GLAccountNo >= @TempGLAccountNoFrom) AND (G.GLAccountNo <= @TempGLAccountNo))AND
((G.DocumentNumber >= @TempDocumentNumberFrom) AND (G.DocumentNumber <= @TempDocumentNumberTo))
AND (cast(sal.BillingDate as date) between cast(@TempFromDate as date)
AND cast(@TempToDate as date))
AND ISNULL(g.Active,0)= 1
AND ((G.BusinessArea = @BusinessArea or @BusinessArea is null))
```

Comment: You would have to define necessary and un-necessary duplicates for us - because we have no idea. Sample data and expected results are required.

Answer (score -1):

Use union all then write an outer query to filter out unnecessary duplicates through defining them in where clause.

```
select * from (
select Com.CompanyCode, B.BranchCode,P.ProjectCode as 'ProjectCode',G.GLAccountNo,COA.ShortText, G.DocCurrency, G.DocCurrencyAmount, 
G.Currency as 'localCurrecny', G.Amount as 'LocalAmount', S.InvoiceNo as 'Reference', 
cast(S.BillingDocumentNumber as varchar(100)) as 'DocumentNumber', '' as 'Document Type',
cast(S.BillingDate as date) as 'PostingDate', cast(S.PODate as date) as 'DocmentDate', 
G.DC,'' as 'Clearing Document', S.AccountingAssignment as 'Assignment', 
'' as 'Department', '' as 'ServiceLineCode','' as 'ProjectCode', '' as 'OffSettingAcctNo', S.TextDescription as 'Text'
from GLedger G
left join Company Com on G.CompanyID = Com.CompanyID
left join Branch B on G.BusinessArea = B.BranchCode
--inner join LedgerTypes L on G.LedgerType_ID = L.ID
inner join Sales S on G.MainID = S.SalesID and G.LedgerType_ID = '3'
left join Projects P on S.AccAssignmentWBSElementID = p.Project_ID
Left join COA on G.GLAccountNo=COA.GLAccount

where
(G.CompanyID = @CompanyID)AND
((G.GLAccountNo >= @TempGLAccountNoFrom) AND (G.GLAccountNo <= @TempGLAccountNo))AND
((G.DocumentNumber >= @TempDocumentNumberFrom) AND (G.DocumentNumber <= @TempDocumentNumberTo))
AND (cast(S.BillingDate as date) between cast(@TempFromDate as date)
AND cast(@TempToDate as date))
AND ISNULL(g.Active,0)= 1
AND ((G.BusinessArea = @BusinessArea or @BusinessArea is null))

union all

select Com.CompanyCode, B.BranchCode,P.ProjectCode as 'ProjectCode',G.GLAccountNo,COA.ShortText, G.DocCurrency, G.DocCurrencyAmount, 
G.Currency as 'localCurrecny', G.Amount as 'LocalAmount', '' as 'Reference', cast(G.DocumentNumber as varchar(100)) as 'DocumentNumber', 
'' as 'Document Type',sal.BillingDate as 'PostingDate', CAST(st.PricingDate as date) as 'DocmentDate', G.DC,'' as 'Clearing Document', '' as 'Assignment', 
D.DepartmentCode as 'Department', S.Name as 'ServiceLineCode', P.ProjectCode as 'ProjectCode', '' as 'OffSettingAcctNo', '' as 'Text'
from GLedger G
left join Company Com on G.CompanyID = Com.CompanyID
left join Branch B on G.BusinessArea = B.BranchCode
--inner join LedgerTypes L on G.LedgerType_ID = L.ID
inner join SalesTransactions ST on G.SubID = ST.SalesTransactionID and G.LedgerType_ID = '4'
left join Department D on G.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID
left join ServiceLineMaster S on G.ServiceLineID = S.ID
left join Projects P on ST.ProjectID = p.Project_ID
Left join COA on G.GLAccountNo=COA.GLAccount
inner join Sales sal
on sal.SalesID= st.SalesID

where
(G.CompanyID = @CompanyID)AND
((G.GLAccountNo >= @TempGLAccountNoFrom) AND (G.GLAccountNo <= @TempGLAccountNo))AND
((G.DocumentNumber >= @TempDocumentNumberFrom) AND (G.DocumentNumber <= @TempDocumentNumberTo))
AND (cast(sal.BillingDate as date) between cast(@TempFromDate as date)
AND cast(@TempToDate as date))
AND ISNULL(g.Active,0)= 1
AND ((G.BusinessArea = @BusinessArea or @BusinessArea is null))
)t
where .....
```